# Manage a Floating IP on AWS Services

Tags: amazon-web-services, floating-ip

Let's pretend I have an AWS EIP allocated as:  eipalloc-94eb5af1
Let's pretent I have an AWS Network Interface:  eni-e3d20a9a, eni-e3d20a9a

Let's now pretent I have two EC2 servers.  The network interfaces are on those two servers.

Now...let's suppose I wanted to setup monitoring.  Ping monitoring perhaps.  If eni-e3d20a9a becomes invisible, I wish to transfer the EIP to eni-e3d20a9a.

This can be easily accomplished by:

```
aws ec2 associate-address --allocation-id eipalloc-03d3b666 \
    --allow-reassociation --network-interface-id eni-98e03bd3
```

Also, setup of a rudimentary bash script on each server to monitor each other is rather simple.

But, I need advice on doing this efficiently on AWS.  Not with a script  Perhaps with Lambda or Cloudwatch?

What is the best way to accomplish the EIP move?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct that you can monitor an instance and, in case of failure, **re-associate an Elastic IP Address** to a different instance or network interface.

There is no automatic facility to performing this monitoring/switching for you. You could monitor your instance from a script on an EC2 instance, from a scheduled AWS Lambda function or even from a computer anywhere on the Internet. However, **you would be responsible for that script**.

Alternatively, you could have the instances themselves **send a custom metric to Amazon CloudWatch on a regular basis** and then create an alarm that will trigger if the metric value changes (eg has not updated lately, indicating a potential system failure). The alarm could trigger an AWS Lambda function that would re-associate the Elastic IP address.

Or, another idea is to **use Amazon Route 53 with a Health Check**. If the Amazon Route 53 health checkers detect a problem, they can change the resolution of a DNS name to an alternate IP address. This is not re-associating an Elastic IP address. Rather, it is changing the IP address returned when a DNS name is resolved.

Comment: Thanks.  Answer is clear.

This IP address is white listed by several of my customers.  So, can't do the DNS way.

I also thought of routing table updates on route tables in the VPC.

My choice will be a bash script pinging every 5 seconds and move the IP as necessary.  I will run this script from a monitoring server within the VPC (which also houses an ELK cluster).

Since the IP floats between haproxy servers participating in peer session sharing, I shouldn't see any "down" time in any 5 second interval.

Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem right, you have to switch the EIP if one instance which acts as a primary goes down to a second instance, and now this secondary/backup instance will act as a primary.

If my above understanding is right, you can use keepalived to automatically monitor and switch elastic IP between instances

This link have example how to do the same
https://www.peternijssen.nl/high-availability-haproxy-keepalived-aws/